# Express + Passport session works in Postman but not in browser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, cookies, axios

I have a node js server running on `http://localhost:9000`

and a client with react js running on `http://localhost:3000`

I am able to authenticate user by making a post request in endpoint `http:localhost:9000/api/v1/authenticate` and send a cookie to client as you can see on my `response header`

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 51
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2020 14:03:48 GMT
ETag: W/"33-tyk8lJX6mfHZ8N08Hj//Q3TUtmY"
Expect-CT: max-age=0
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3ALVe2uJLDGv502_M70nCSfjfawWhXG0Zx.zDCxMUAJE54wKO0ecJogSPLWZIQoOdHqF387XEX1A7E; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 08 Jan 2021 14:03:48 GMT; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

And now after I logged in and check if user is authenticated `/check-session`,
I am able to get the data in POSTMAN and `req.session.passport` data exist.

But am not able to get the same result when I make a request in frontend with `axios`

```
export const checkAuthSession = async () => {
    try {
        const req = await axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/check-session',
            withCredentials: true,
        });

        return Promise.resolve(req.data);
    } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
}
```

I expect to get `200` status and get the data after login in frontend but I get the 404.

These are the `request` and `response` header after I make the request with axios:

**Request Header**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3Ag7erGfrj2XWv5jrFXrSk4kJH-qvuCCa7.8e2cnCs1dduo86Ydne1sPDRSoAlYwdiAbGcZJqluZgc
Host: localhost:9000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36 Edg/87.0.664.66
```

**Response Header**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 9
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2020 14:17:18 GMT
ETag: W/"9-0gXL1ngzMqISxa6S1zx3F4wtLyg"
Expect-CT: max-age=0
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

And this is how I configured CORS in express:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true
}));
```

Comment: Show a code where you set a base url for `axios`

Comment: I set the base url like this: ```axios.defaults.baseURL = `${foodieUrl}/api/${foodieApiVersion}`; //http:localhost:9000/api/v1```

Comment: It should be `http://localhost:9000/api/v1`

Comment: @Anatoly Yes that's what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer:

In my axios request, I was only setting the `withCredentials: true` options in my `/check-session` endpoint.

To fix it, I must set the credentials for all request.

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

As MDN also said:

> For a CORS request with credentials, in order for browsers to expose the response to frontend JavaScript code, both the server (using the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header) and the client (by setting the credentials mode for the XHR, Fetch, or Ajax request) must indicate that they’re opting in to including credentials.